# python add time to a countdown already running

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, countdown

I want to have an app where if I click a button I add X amount of time to my running countdown timer.

I'm guessing I have to use threads for this but am not sure how to implement it..

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def countdown_controller(add_time):
    end_it = False
    def timer(time_this):
        start = time.time()
        lastprinted = 0
        finish = start + time_this
        while time.time() < finish:
            now = int(time.time())
            if now != lastprinted:
                time_left = int(finish - now)
                print time_left
                lastprinted = now
            if end_it == True:
                now = finish
            time.sleep(0.1)
    # Check if the counter is running otherwise just add time.
    try:
        time_left 
    except NameError:
        timer(add_time)
    else:
        if time_left == 0:
        timer(add_time)
        else:
            add_this = time_left
            end_it = True
            while now != finish:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            timer(add_time + add_this)
```

Obviously this will not work, because every time I call `countdown_controller(15)` fx, it will start counting down for 15 seconds and if I click my button nothing happens until the timer is ended.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there is a flaw in the design of the code, because your screen output blocks down the entire program doing nothing (`time.sleep(0.1)`).

Typically what you want to to do in these cases is **having a main loop in your program that cycles through the various operations that make your program run**. This guarantees a sensible distribution of system resources between the various tasks.

In your specific case, what you would like to have in your main loop is:

- Check user input (has extra time been added?)
- Update output of the countdown

Example implementation:

```
import time
import curses

# The timer class    
class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.target = time.time() + 5
    def add_five(self):
        self.target += 5
    def get_left(self):
        return int(self.target-time.time())

# The main program
t = Timer()
stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.nodelay(True)
curses.noecho()
# This is the main loop done in curses, but you can implement it with
# a GUI toolkit or any other method you wish.
while True:
    left = t.get_left()
    if left <= 0:
        break
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Seconds left: %s ' % str(left).zfill(3))
    c = stdscr.getch()
    if c == ord('x') :
        t.add_five()
# Final operations start here
stdscr.keypad(0)
curses.echo()
curses.endwin()
print '\nTime is up!\n'
```

The above program will increase the counter of 5 seconds if you press the `x` key (lowercase). Most of the code is boilerplate to use the `curses` module, but of course if you use PyGTK, PySide or any other graphical toolkit, it will be different.

**EDIT:** As a rule of thumb, in python you want to avoid threading as much as you can, both because it often (but not always) slows down programs (see "[Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)") and because it makes software harder to debug/maintain.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Mac for the example, I will try out your idea with my code! I do already have a main loop running checking for other tings so I really like your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have a `Timer` object with a `finish` attribute that I could simply add an int to. Have that `timer` running in another thread that you can then query for the current time remaining from your GUI.

```
class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.finish = time.time() + length

    def get_time(self):
        return time.time() >= self.finish
```